# icons on windows 10 toolbar to small how to increase the size any help please

Tags: windows, windows-10

New laptop is windows 10 the icons on the toolbar are very  small any ideas on how to increase the size of them please ? I have tried googling it but to no avail please help

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click on the main taskbar and ensure that `Lock all taskbars` is unchecked.
2. Right-click on the toolbar for which you want large icons, and select `View->Large Icons`.
3. Re-lock "all taskbars"

Answer (score 0):

1. Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key.
2. Type **scale**
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. In *Scale and layout* choose **150%**.

Alternative description of the steps: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5990-change-dpi-scaling-level-displays-windows-10-a.html#option1

Answer (score 0):

> Right-click the **Taskbar** > **Taskbar settings** > and ensure that
>   the slider labeled **Use small taskbar buttons** is set to **Off** –
>   [Run5k](https://superuser.com/users/650163/run5k)

[image]

Comment: It's great that you're converting comment answers into answers.  Comment posters can post an answer if they want.  But if they choose not to, and you expand the comment into an answer as you did here, there's no reason to make that community wiki.  You put the work into capturing the screenshot and annotating it.  Why not get the rep?  Just sayin'.